# module has no attribute error after using write() function

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that writes another script, then calls a function from it. Using the code below, I keep getting `module has no attribute 'helloWorld'` as an error. The file exists, and has the function below in it, so I don't know why it's throwing this error. Is something wrong with the spacing? How can I rewrite this to make it do what I'm trying to do?

```
import test
with open("test.py", "a") as f:
    f.write("def helloWorld(): print 'hello world'")

test.helloWorld()
```

Comment: Please post the code from `test`, also notice, I hope that's not the actual name of the package because it's already used by built-in packages

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You import test, then overwrite it with some new code; but the file has already been loaded by that point. I can't understand what you are trying to do but this is certainly not the way to do it.

Comment: @ChenAsraf to wit: https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html

Comment: Technically you could `reload(test)` after you write and that would work. You should also  add a newline char `("def helloWorld(): print('hello world')\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you `write` the new function **after** you `import`. Python reads the file when you import from it and stores the necessary information in memory; it doesn't go back and look at the file every time you call a function from it (if you think about it, this is **a good thing**, as otherwise all kinds of disastrous things could happen at runtime).

Python has extensive introspection functionality and is highly dynamic, so you can do things like patching a function into a module at runtime without messing around with the file. Alternatively, rearrange a bit:

```
with open("test.py", "a") as f:
    f.write("def helloWorld(): print 'hello world'")

import test

test.helloWorld()
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem.  I imported a blank file and then tried to modify it after the fact!  Thank you for not downvoting me like everyone else, this issue is now resolved.

Comment: @user3150635 you've had only one downvote, and how do you know it wasn't from me?

Comment: because everyone was being unproductive, and if you thought it was a stupid question like the person who downvoted it, you wouldn't have given such a productive and helpful answer.

Comment: @user3150635 you've also only had four comments: one perfectly reasonable request for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (the question *still* doesn't mention that `test.py` starts out blank); two comments from Daniel and Padraic that could serve as answers themselves; and a link from me. If you think *this* is *"everyone being unproductive"*, you're in for a rough ride!